# after glBindTexture(CUBE_MAP)() glError (0x502)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, google-project-tango

In android ndk, I am developing an app where I have give textureid to an api & sample the texels. When called that function, I am getting this error.

mycode,

```
Gluint textureID;
glGenTexture(1,&textureID);
videoOverlay(textureID);
```

Logcat:

```
I/frame-renderer﹕ Warning: Using sw texture path
I/frame-renderer﹕ after glBindTexture(CUBE_MAP)() glError (0x502)
W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <__load_uniform_int:319>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Please let me know if anybody has answer for this.

Comment: Can you show your actual code? I assume since this is tagged [tag:android-ndk] that it's supposed to be C, but that's not how you call `glBindTexture` in C.

Comment: The fact is i am accessing an api from google where I have to give texture as input to get image. i updated post with my code

Comment: This code doesn't seem related. But I am guessing that `videoOverlay (...)` expects a cubemap texture rather than a 2D texture. You initialized `textureID` as a 2D texture 1 line prior to calling `videoOverlay`. Try not binding the texture at all before calling `videoOverlay`.